# sessions will be null when want to use download managers Like [Internet Download Manager] for download a file

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, download, session-variables

my code in page_load is like below :

```
    if (Session["User_ID"] != null)
    {
        GO FOR DOWNLOAD FILES
    }
```

the User_ID session will be create when a user logins to my web site.
after user's login when he wants to download a file with Internet Download Manager (right click on link and choosing Dwonload With IDM) Session["User_ID"] shows us null.
i used Session["User_ID"] for some limitations.
how can i fix this issue for my purpose?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix it by not relying on the session. Before redirecting to the download url stash  the info you need into the cache keyed off a random string. Then pass the random string along the url. On the download page use the url string to load the cached data. No session required.

Answer (score 1):

You can't it is the download manager software that is at fault not your code.  It is simply connecting to your url without passing the relevant cookies that asp.net uses to maintain session state so the server just sees it as a new unauthenticated connection. It as if the user logged in in firefox then copied and pasted the download url into chrome.

Comment: thanks for answer, so what can i do about limitations? is there another way?

Comment: would u plz explain about this sentence -> It as if the user logged in in firefox then copied and pasted the download url into chrome. -> what is ur mean? copy and paste url from firefox to chrome does not help that user to download a file without permission(he should login first)!

Comment: You can allow unauthenticated users to download (i.e. remove the check) or accept that some crappy third party piece of software doesn't work with your site plus thousands of other sites i.e. it's not your problem.

Comment: The user logs in in firefox, they are authenticated, they copy an paste the url into chrome (where they haven't logged in), the request comes through as unauthenticated .  This is the same as the download manager i.e. it works like a different browser.

Comment: how can i prevent third party softwares and recognize them?

Comment: You might be able to detect things like download managers by the user agent string in the request header but they often spoof it to look like a browser.  You can't write any server side code that can reliably detect software that is installed on the users PC.

Comment: This is correct information, but it doesn't really answer the question of how to fix it.

Comment: @SamuelNeff Not everything can be fixed sometimes the correct answer to the question is "no you can't do that".

Comment: True, but this is not a "no you can't do that" problem. This is a common situation that developers should know how to deal with.